# Strange Laravel Database Error On Live Site

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have just uploaded my new website, which is coded using the Laravel framework, to my hosting provided (Godaddy).

All is working fine except I just encountered a bizzare error.

Upon filling out a form, the user data is stored in my database. It was moaning about just one table:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'jqexchange.Applicants_phones' doesn't exist (SQL: truncate `Applicants_phones`)
```

Now if I rename applicants_phones (lower case table name) to Applicants_phones, it then gives me the same error message but with: 'jqexchange.applicants_phones'.

I have it working now by creating both tables which seems stupid. Regardless, the data is going into the right table (applicants_phones).

Anyone have an idea as to why this is?

Comment: What have in your relationship method, did you used explicit pivot table name?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your local dev is on Windows and your server is Linux.

Because MySQL tables map to files on the filesystem, Windows MySQL table names are case-insensitive (because the Windows filesystem is), but on Linux they're case sensitive.

Comment: But why will it only work if both versions of the table name exist?

Comment: @imperium2335 I suspect you've typed it in some spots as uppercase and others as lowercase.